# What laws are the same in all string theory compactifications?

Tags: string-theory, multiverse, string-theory-landscape

In the string theory landscape, the set of particles we observe, their masses and interaction strengths originate from one of many different possible compactifications. What fundamental physical reality/principles/laws is the same in all string theory compactifications/universes in the landscape?

Comment: Assuming that string theory is a quantum field theory, the laws of quantum mechanics would hold.

Comment: Would all compactificatiosn preserve at least some part of the Poincare group? (just as our universe presumably preserves 4d Poincare)

Comment: String theory is not a quantum field theory, they are structurally different http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+theory+FAQ#RelationshipBetweenQuantumFieldTheoryAndStringTheory and it is relativistic, so quantum mechanics would not apply. We can not say much more than that all (viable) string theories reduce to standard model and general relativity in appropriate limits, other than that they can accomodate pretty much anything.

Comment: This question should not be closed.

Comment: @Conifold, What on earth do you mean when you say quantum mechanics wouldn't hold? String theory is a quantum theory. The fact that you mention it reduces to the Standard Model in a certain limit corroborates this.

Comment: Agree with @MitchellPorter - this question should be left open. Fine, it's research level, but it isn't too unclear in my opinion. I may answer myself if I get a moment this afternoon!

Comment: @SurgicalCommander No, you are confusing quantum theory with quantum mechanics. Most of "quantum theory" is understood to be quantum *field* theory at its core, with quantum mechanics only appearing as a certain limit. Of course, string theory is itself not a quantum field theory, but it's still a quantum theory that is *not* quantum mechanics unless you apply a nonrelativistic approximation. I guess this is all a matter of semantics though, so let's not get too wound up over it ;)

Comment: It's not even clear what "laws" are supposed to be here, in my opinion. Do you mean certain symmetries? Do you mean actual equations of motion (which is what is most often called a "physical law")? Do you mean the field content of the low energy effective QFT?

Comment: @ACuriousMind yes. all of that are laws or fundamental properties

Answer (score 1):

One answer to your question, which laws of physics should be reproduced in any string compactification, could be the following: 
If the Weak Gravity Conjecture, see http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0601001, holds true, then gravity should come out as the weakest force in any string compactification. (Notice that there are - as far as I know - only arguments for the WGC coming from generic considerations of a theory of Quantum Gravity.)

Moreover, one can hope to find constraints on certain SM or cosmological parameters from string compactifications. For instance, the energy scale of inflation must not be too high, b/c otherwise one risks destabilisation of the extra dimensions. This translates into upper bounds on the field range of the inflaton. (By the way: If the WGC is true, then certain scenarios of natural inflation cannot be realised.)

psm

Comment: Is this related to the so-called swampland? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swampland_%28physics%29

Comment: If the WGC is correct and if in an effective field theory gravity is not the weakest force, then this EFT sits in the so-called swampland but is not part of the string theory landscape.

Answer (score -4):

these fundamental properties are unexplained and the same in all compactifications: totalitarian principle. speed of light. space has quantum jitters. space can expand. space can create particles. particles experience up to 4 forces at low energy, 1 of them know about all particles, 3 of them know about only some particles

Comment: somewhere pertinent but it's efficient. Please let's know some links, preferably well signed.